# The meaning of the word "handsome"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-meaning

I have read a film review and i'm confused now with the word "handsome" and "a clever anti-Pygmalion" in this sentence:

> Blockquote This handsome movie about the abdication crisis and George VI's stammer is a clever anti-Pygmalion

Could you please paraphrase and explain me

Answer (score 2):

The word "handsome" isn't often used alongside the word "movie". I'd say it's an attempt by film critics to be creative with language. Of [the meanings of the word "handsome"](http://thefreedictionary.com/handsome), the one that suits this usage case most is:

> having pleasing proportions or arrangements, as of shapes or colors; attractive

(Webster's, listed third on TheFreeDictionary page).

Since it really is very unusual to see words "handsome" and "movie" together (although another critic did use this combination in 2004 [to describe "The Aviator"](http://content.time.com/time/magazine/article/0,9171,1101041220-1006649,00.html)), I wouldn't claim to know what it is *exactly* that the critic means. Probably that the movie is well-cut, with aesthetically pleasing settings etc.

Regarding "anti-Pygmalion", it's a reference to "Pygmalion", [a play by George Bernard Shaw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pygmalion_(play)) (made into a [musical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Fair_Lady)<sup>([RU](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8_(%D0%BC%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB)))</sup> and at some point into [a film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Fair_Lady_(film))), in which Professor Higgins works with a working-class girl who cannot speak in a cultured way, improving her pronunciation and grammar. He thus shapes her into a real lady and falls in love with her, the same way that the Greek [Pygmalion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pygmalion_(mythology)) made a beautiful statue from uncut stone and fell in love with it.

Since Proffessor Higgins *improves* the way that Eliza Doolittle *speaks*, apparently, George VI's *stammer* is about an opposite situation—an individual from the highest class possible who can't speak correctly.